# Наследование от инициализированного класса

Tags: python, ооп, python-2.x

Python 2.7

Есть возможность наследовать свойства из класса в класс:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.aa = a


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        A.__init__(self, a)
        self.bb = b

c = B(10, "qwerty")
print c.aa, c.bb
```

В данном примере потомка можно создать только с нуля - заново. А как наследовать инициализированного родителя? Т.е. взять и от экземпляра `c` наплодить потомков?

"Лобовой" вариант: входным параметром класс и всё переопределить из него, но хотелось бы избежать этого, т.к. придётся перебирать всё свойства и методы по-новой.

Меня интересует именно перенос всех свойств и методов из объекта в другой через инициализацию или метод. Также задачу можно решить слиянием двух классов например.

Для примера имеем 2 класса (представляйте что там не по одному а по гигантскому количеству свойств и методов):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.aa = a

    def get_list_aa(self):
        return list(self.aa)

class B:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.bb = b

    def get_tuple_bb(self):
        return tuple(self.bb)
```

Пробую получить `C1` - просто слияние двух инициализированных объектов-классов, или `C2` - использование в основе (наследование от инициализированного объекта-класса по сути) - результат такого содержания:

```
class C1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.aa = 'any value'
        self.bb = 'any_value'

    def get_list_aa(self):
        return list(self.aa)

    def get_tuple_bb(self):
        return tuple(self.bb)

class C2:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.aa = 'any value'
        self.bb = b

    def get_list_aa(self):
        return list(self.aa)

    def get_tuple_bb(self):
        return tuple(self.bb)
```

Comment: Никак. Наследование возможно только от класса. Какую задачу вы решаете? Если вам нужны копии объекта `c`, то просто добавьте в класс `B` метод, который позволяет получить копию экземпляра.

Comment: я хочу создать новый объект1 с забором значений свойств и методов из уже инициализированного объекта2

Comment: @EugeneDennis, напишите метод `clone`, который вернет копию текущего

Comment: @gil9red я добавил ответ с вариантом, на котором остановился, в нём при инициализации осуществляется clone через разбор `__dict__`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант, через перебор `__dict__`, "топорен", но работает:

```
import functools

class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.aa = a

    def get_list_aa(self):
        return list(self.aa)

class B:
    def __init__(self, parent, b):
        self.bb = b
        for attr, val in parent.__dict__.iteritems():
            if attr.startswith("__"):
                continue
            self.__dict__[attr] = val
        for attr, val in parent.__class__.__dict__.iteritems():
            if attr.startswith("__"):
                continue
            if not callable(val):
                continue
            self.__dict__[attr] = functools.partial(val, self)

    def get_tuple_bb(self):
        return tuple(self.bb)

insta = A('first value')
instb = B(insta, 'second value')

print instb.__dict__
print instb.get_list_aa()
print instb.get_tuple_bb()
```

Answer (score 0):

Термин "наследование" применим только к классам. То, что хотите сделать вы, правильнее назвать "копированием" объектов.

Реализовать можно, например, так:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.aa = a


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        A.__init__(self, a)
        self.bb = b

    # Добавляем этот метод
    def copy(self):
        return self.__class__(self.aa, self.bb)


c_1 = B(10, "qwerty")
print c_1.aa, c_1.bb

c_2 = c_1.copy()
print c_2.aa, c_2.bb
```